# Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '

Tags: javascript

I've implemented an rAF(requestAnimationFrame) setup for my game loop:

```
draw: function (x, y) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          Player.draw(150, 150);
        });

        //drawing code: worked perfectly with setInterval

    }, 1000 / 60);
},
```

It's in a `Player` object, in a `draw` function. I call:

```
Player.draw(Player.x, Player.y);
```

at the bottom of the code.

From what I've seen on similar questions, the images need to be declared before this is evaluated. I have loaded my images at the top using an immediately called function:

```
var images = [];

x = 0;

(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = ('../webgame/assets/images/survivor-idle_shotgun_' + i + '.png');
    };
})(); // This worked perfectly with setInterval too
```

However I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

it points to this line of code:

```
ctx.drawImage(images[this.spriteCostumeCount], this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
```

in the drawing code.

How can I get the player sprite to be animated using this requestAnimationFrame and how can I fix this error?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(images[this.spriteCostumeCount])` before the line where the error appear, so you can see its type and properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `images[this.spriteCostumeCount]` is defined and of the correct type.

An easy way to test this would be to add a `console.log(typeof images[this.spriteCostumeCount])` right before you call the `drawImage` method.

If the result is undefined, you can encapsulate the call in a `if` condition. If it is defined, make sure the value is a type that is accepted by the `drawImage` method.

Comment: Yeah for some reason it's undefined. What exactly should I encapsulate?

Comment: Also, I logged the whole array. It shows up as a array of "img" objects

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but maybe try to create an HTMLImageElement using the createElement method described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement in the example section.